# VBA - custom for-loop

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I would like to copy certain tables from one sheet to another. To do this I have the following code:

```
Dim start As Long
Dim eind As Long
Dim output As Long
Dim tbl As Range
Dim dest As Range

output = 5   

For start = 3 To 224 Step 13
        end = start + 10
        Set tbl = Sheets("Model").Range("C" & start & ":E" & end)
        Set dest = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & output).Resize(tbl.Rows.Count, tbl.Columns.Count)
        dest.Value = tbl.Value
        output = output + 16
Next start
```

However, this code copies ALL tables from "Model" to "Sheet1". I only want the tables with names A, B, C, E, G, H, J and L. (The names are in D2, D15, D28, D41, etc).

Is there a way to define these specific tables before the for-loop and incorporate this in the loop? Or is there another way to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going through the calculations in your code...

(I think there is a misalignment: you want to loop from `For start = 3 To 224 Step 13` , however you want to check the names in D2, D15, D28. So maybe it should be `For start = 2 ....` I am not sure since you didn't share your Sheet Data structure.)

Anyway, to add the condition inside the loop just use the code below:

```
For start = 3 To 224 Step 13
    end = start + 10

    Select Case Sheets("Model").Range("D" & start - 1) ' I have "start -1" to adjust to rows 2, 15, 28, etc.

        ' copy only Tables with the following names in Column D...
        Case "A", "B", "C", "E", "G", "H", "J", "L"
            Set tbl = Sheets("Model").Range("C" & start & ":E" & end)
            Set dest = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & output).Resize(tbl.Rows.Count, tbl.Columns.Count)
            dest.Value = tbl.Value

    End Select

    output = output + 16
Next start
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this was what I was looking for. BTW, there is no misalignment as I only want to copy the content of the table, excluding the header, while the table name is in the header.

Comment: It does not work as hoped. Because in the output sheet, I get a blank space where table D was located in the source sheet, as I do not copy this table. I would like to have A, B, C, E, G, H, J and L directly below each other. Do you understand what I am saying?

Comment: @LauZ this is not what your post was about. Either you add a screen-shot of both sheets (simulated input and output). Or you can mark this as answer, and open a new post. It will allow also other users on SO a chance to answer it.